# Do the last two seasons of Berserk contain nudity?

Tags: berserk

I want to start watching *Berserk*, but at the same time, I prefer not seeing explicit nudity.

Do the last two seasons of *Berserk* contain nudity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it contains nudity and some of the most twisted sex-related scenes I've seen in anime (later I found a YouTube video including it in the top 10 of most twisted scenes in animes), one of them (careful, *sensitive content below*)

> including Lady Farnese and a horse.

When I saw it, I thought, "What's going on here, is this aired on TV?" As a matter of fact, I believe an anime like that would be forbidden for all ages in some (or many?) countries.

Answer (score 2):

The manga did contain plenty of nudity, and also features both consensual and non-consensual sex.

After quickly skimming through several parts for the last 2 seasons, I can confirm that it contains scenes where fully and partially naked people present.

This part of the story also features a 'naked elf' companion, which will be featured throughout most of the season, as he travels with Guts.

Judging by the IMDB [Parents Guide](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5847454/parentalguide), there are at least 10 counts of sex and nudity. However, IMDB also makes mention this is the rating of the uncensored version. Hence if you are not a fan of such things, I would suggest you watch the censored version.

Comment: I sincerely apologize for having you go through that.

Comment: @Luyw No worries. I have nothing against such content. And overall the content within the manga is a lot less civil then in the anime.